# Host a file on heroku for downloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Very simple question. Couple of hours of googling but couldn't find an answer!! How can I upload a pdf file on heroku so that my website visitors can download it?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add pdf to your Git then push to Heroku.
Create a download method as follows,

```
  def download
    file = "#{Rails.root}/file.pdf"
    if File.exists?(file)
      send_file file, :type=>"application/pdf", :x_sendfile=>true
    else
      flash[:notice] = 'File not found'
      redirect_to :index
    end
  end
```

Make necessary changes if needed.

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Comment: Hi, in which folder do you put this file please ?